# Is it possible to change the default shell in Netbeans? If so, how?

Tags: netbeans

In Netbeans 13, when opening a terminal, by going to 'Window -> IDE Tools -> Terminal', a new terminal is opened. But I can't see a way to change the shell that runs on the terminal.

In my case on a Mac, the default shell used by Netbeans is `zsh`. I would like it to start with `bash`. Is this possible to do?

Thank you all for the attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NetBeans` on MacOS uses the environment variable `SHELL` to get information about which shell to start. MacOS puts there the path for the default shell for your account. So basically NetBeans just opens the terminal with the default shell.

Check what shell is configured as default:

```
MacBook-Pro-Admin:~ admin$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

[Change default](https://www.howtogeek.com/444596/how-to-change-the-default-shell-to-bash-in-macos-catalina/) shell to bash for your account:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Enter your password when prompted. After that, you need to reboot the computer. NetBeans should now open the bash shell.

An alternative approach is to change `SH` variable in `hostinfo.sh` script. NetBeans uses `hostinfo.sh` script to get the current path to the default shell. I wouldn't recommend it but as a temporary hack, it would do what you want.
Got to the location of `hostinfo.sh`. For my installation of 12.2, it is here.

```
/Applications/NetBeans/Apache NetBeans 12.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/ide/bin/nativeexecution
```

Then open file hostinfo.sh go to the end of the file and change the line:

```
echo SH=${SHELL}
```

to:

```
echo SH=/bin/bash
```

Then restart NetBeans.